# Create search box in the list in react js component

Tags: reactjs

Please tell, how to carry out search in the list of components which code is specified below correctly?
The search should be performed by title or full description of the list item.
Component with list of Item components:

```
const PathItems = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const pathDescription = useSelector(state => state.firestore.ordered.pathDescription);
    const handleClick = (path) => {
        dispatch(selectPath(path));
    }
    if(pathDescription && pathDescription.length !== 0){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="pl-0 border-right border-dark">
                        {pathDescription && pathDescription.map(item => (
                            <PathItem
                                key={item.id}
                                item={item}
                                onInfoChange={ handleClick }
                            />
                        ))}
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <FullDecript/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <h5 className="text-muted text-center text-middle">Add your first route</h5>
        )
    }

}
export default compose(firestoreConnect(()=> ['pathDescription']))(PathItems);
```

Item component code:

```
const PathItem = ({ item, onInfoChange }) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        onInfoChange(item);
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Card as="a"
                  style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                  className={'mb-2'}
                  onClick={ handleClick }>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                        <Col xs={1}>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={7}>
                            <h5>{item.title}</h5>
                            {item.sDescript}
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={4} className="text-right">
                            <label>{item.length}600 km</label>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default PathItem;
```

General view of the described components
[image: General view of the described components]
Thanks in advance)

Comment: You could try setting up a useState that holds the value of the text input and then use the useEffect hook to filter through your data, returning only the items that match your input query stored in the state. Then in your html you would show only those elements that match (maybe through using another state that holds the items that match). If that was confusing, let me know and I can explain a bit more. :)

Comment: @ShreyJoshi Thanks for the answer. Maybe you can give a sample code?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
const [searchQuery, setQuery] = useState("");

    const inputEvent = (event) => {
        const data = event.target.value;
        console.log(pathDescription);
        setQuery(data);
    }

    const filterItems = pathDescription && pathDescription.filter(item => {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.fDescript.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase());
    })
...
<Col className="pl-0 border-right border-dark" style={divStyle}>
                        <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Type..."
                                aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
                                value={ searchQuery }
                                onChange={ inputEvent }
                            />
                            <InputGroup.Append>
                                <Button variant="outline-secondary">
                                    <img
                                        alt="Logo"
                                        src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/app-user-interface-line/64/search_focus_user_interface_app_zoom-256.png"
                                        width="25"
                                        height="25"
                                        className="d-inline-block align-top"/>
                                </Button>
                            </InputGroup.Append>
                        </InputGroup>
                        {filterItems.sort((a, b) => b.favorite - a.favorite).map(item => (
                            <PathItem
                                key={item.id}
                                item={item}
                                onInfoChange={ handleClick }
                            />
                        ))}
                    </Col>
```